# When should I build a project?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, build, gruntjs

Let's say my project is an `npm` package and I am using `webpack` or `grunt` to bundle my css, js, img files into `dist` directory. The build script is defined in `package.json`.

What is the right time to run the build script ? Should I run it in the dev env, and commit the changed `dist` directory ? Or should I have a git pull hook to do it ? Or should I build it on my dev env and upload the final code to my production ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase or AWS, they have CLI-based deployment features. You can include these tools in your package.json on your build script.

I tried following this guide and it worked for me: 
https://johnlouros.com/blog/uploading-a-angular-app-to-S3-with-npm

Comment: Might make sense to ask the OP if those techs are used or at all relevant before answering since they weren't mentioned or tagged.

Comment: Hi Dave. Point taken. My answer is just a reference on how he can tackle his current dilemma. But you are right. Thanks for pointing that out.